# Abstracting @Injectable with Angular Ivy does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, angular-ivy

#### Update

- Opened issue for this question https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34721

#### Intro

In Angular Services are provided using the decorator `@Injectable`.

```
@Injectable() // -> works
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

#### Abstracting @Injectable

Before Ivy, it was possible to build an abstraction for `@Injectable` (e.g. for configuring the provider dynamically, enhancing the service class).

The following snippet shows an example how `@Injectable` can be wrapped.

```
function InjectableEnhanced() {
  return <T extends new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType<T>>(target: T) => {
    Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })(target);
  };
}
```

Using the decorator `InjectableEnhanced` (see above) does not work while Ivy is enabled.
The following code snipped causes a runtime error.

```
@InjectableEnhanced() // -> does not work
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

#### Runtime error

Compiling the service using `@InjectableEnhanced` with angular/cli works, but the following error is shown in the browser. The corresponding project can be found at https://github.com/GregOnNet/ng-9-inject.git.

[image]

Maybe, the Angular compiler does some code transformation but is not able any more to resolve @Injectable inside other decorators.
Having a look at the angular repository, a reference to JIT-compiler can be found in `injectable.ts` (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/injectable.ts#L14).

#### Question

Is there still a way abstracting @Injectable?

#### Repository for reproduction

https://github.com/GregOnNet/ng-9-inject.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom provider can be created by using some of angular's internal API:

```
import { ɵɵdefineInjectable, ɵɵinject } from "@angular/core";

export function InjectableEnhanced() {
  return <T extends new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType<T>>(target: T) => {
    (target as any).ɵfac = function() {
      throw new Error("cannot create directly");
    };

    (target as any).ɵprov = ɵɵdefineInjectable({
      token: target,
      providedIn: "root",
      factory() {
        // ɵɵinject can be used to get dependency being already registered
        const dependency = ɵɵinject(Dependency); 
        return new target(dependency);
      }
    });
    return target;
  };
}
```

Working example can be found at https://github.com/GregOnNet/ng-9-inject

Comment: seems like in Angular 12 `ɵfac` is only a getter and it's impossible to assign a function to it. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Hi, I recently updated my library and my library still works. But I will double-check this.

Comment: Ok, I verified it too. So it's working with AOT=true. But for non-aot builds with Ivy Angular  adds `ɵfac` and `ɵprov` getters which you cannot modify. For this case creating normal `Injectable` instance still works like before. I'd only like to know whether there is a way to know if build is aot or not in runtime...

Comment: Ok, so in case someone else has the same problem, here is how to work around it. Instead of `(target as any).ɵprov = ɵɵdefineInjectable` use `Object.defineProperty(target, 'ɵprov', {.....})`

Answer (score 1):

The decorator is getting attached to the constructor as expected, but when the `AppComponent` is created the injector tries to resolve the provider and crashes.

I think the error message is just a generic error for when a component fails construction, but the error is happening when Angular is trying to get the injectables for the `AppComponent` constructor.

If you log the constructor for the service you can see that the provider metadata has been attached:

```js
@InjectableEnhanced()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
  }
}


console.log((MyService as object).prototype.constructor.hasOwnProperty('ɵprov'));
// prints "true"
```

When I try to inspect that property it triggers the error:

```js
try {
  console.log((MyService as object).prototype.constructor.ɵprov);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); // prints the same error message
}
```

I think the property is a *getter* property that resolves to the instance of the provider and that is what is crashing.

The closest issue on Angular that I could find was this one but it's still open:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31495

So I feel like the Ivy compiler might be searching the source code for `@Injectable()` and building a list of expected providers, and it doesn't see this new decorator so the `MyService` is excluded from the list. Later at run-time the metadata for the decorator is there, but the injector doesn't know what it is for and crashes.

I tried to find something documented where you could register a new decorator with the Ivy compiler, but wasn't able to and I don't know if such a thing exist.

FYI: I do this exact same thing on one of my other projects so I think there will be a lot of people effected by this.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. 
It really helps me to dig deeper.

I read https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31495 and also think this could be related. Nevertheless, I will open another issue since IoC is affected here, too.

Comment: @GregorWoiwode can you update your question with a link to the issue that you opened so that others can find it. thanks.